# Qt websocket server example not working

Tags: qt, websocket, qtwebsockets

I am trying the example from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-echoserver-example.html to create a simple websocket server and connect to it via google chrome browser.

I just used the example files, the default port (1234), I built it and the application is running fine "WebSocketServer listening on port 1234". But when I try to connect with the sample html there is no connection. I tried other ports as well.

My problem is I don't know how I can start to debug where the problem is? I don't get any errors or anything. Any ideas what the problem could be? Thanks!

Comment: I already tried to disable it

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer-tool of chrome, the "Console" tab will display some error message after websocket connect timeout.